# I can't get gpg-zip to work. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: encryption, gnupg

I haven't used gpg-zip before. I am trying to compress and encrypt a directory with more than 200 files. I did a test run with a smaller directory containing just a dozen PDFs in it, a folder I'll call "PDFfolder."

`man gpg-zip` offers the following template as a guide for a user named Bob who wants to do this with a directory labeled "mydocs":

> ```
>  gpg-zip --encrypt --output test1 --gpg-args -r Bob mydocs
> ```

I did this precisely, using my email address, which is also attached to my PGP public key, and of course tied to my user ID in my own public key ring:

```
 gpg-zip --encrypt --output test1 --gpg-args -r myemail@emymail.com PDFfolder
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
gpg: missing argument for option "-r"
/bin/tar: myemail@emymail.com: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong?

I should add that the "-r" argument works just fine for me using gpg normally, to encrypt.

Comment: Is "myemail@emymail.com" your ID? `-r` needs the ID, according to the man page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The man page is kind of misleading. There should only be a single parameter following the `--gpg-args`, i.e. you need to quote it properly:

```
  gpg-zip --encrypt --output test1 --gpg-args '-r myemail@emymail.com' PDFfolder
```

Apart from that you can just use the `-r` or `--recipient` option of gpg-zip directly (this is documented), there is no need to use it with `--gpg-args`.